# Will Gnome 43 be included in the upgrades of 22.04 Jammy?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-session

I found information that the bug GLib-CRITICAL is fixed in Gnome 43. Will Gnome 43 be included in an upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Ubuntu does not update its core packages (except security fixes) on a release to maintain stability.

However, Ubuntu does provide point release upgrade for GNOME. For example, Ubuntu 22.04 was released with GNOME 42.0, but now it has been updated to 42.5.

If you really need GNOME 43, you can upgrade to 22.10 or 23.04 (to be released in April 2023).

Comment: Now it is 42.9. I wait for 22.04.3.

Comment: 22.04.3 is not a major version upgrade. If you have 22.04, and perform all updates, it will automatically become 22.04.3. It will also have GNOME 42.X

Comment: Still not fixed.  syslog pollution like this really needs to be addressed -- particularly w/re display configurations since there are so many moving parts involved in tracking down where real problems are in system usability.  red herrings don't help. not having displays working correctly is a major problem with linux systems.

Comment: @JamesBowery What is not fixed? If you are facing a particular issue, please ask a new question